# prebiotics and probiotics dosage & can I have them regularly?

Tags: medications, bacteria, probiotics

I've heard some good things about prebiotics and probiotics - for example, [here](http://chriskresser.com/5-uncommon-uses-for-probiotics/). I also came across this line...

> *As with any dietary supplement, be aware that probiotic supplements are regulated as foods, not drugs - [WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/digestive-disorders/tc/probiotics-topic-overview)*

So, here's my question, can you overdose on prebiotics or probiotics? How much would you have to take? I heard they're natural, but still wanted to know, if having more of those natural bacteria a problem at all? Could it depend on the specific type of bacteria?

Answer (score 2):

There are currently no studies catalogued in PubMed (the largest repository of medical articles) that cover [probiotics and overdoses](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=probiotics%20AND%20overdose) at the time of this answer. (Clicking that link will rerun the search. The one result that comes up is unrelated.)

Theoretically, there should be little to no danger from "overdosing" on probiotic as probiotics are supposed to represent a balance of microflora. The challenge is that our microbiome has been found to be correlated with [obesity, type 2 diabetes, steatosis, cardiovascular diseases, inflammatory bowel diseases](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23616309), [depression](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=microbiome%20AND%20depression), and other mental conditions. Edit: [probiotics can also have profound effects on the skin](https://simpleskincarescience.com/probiotics-for-skin/) as newer research is revealing.

As a result, it is not yet fully clear how changing our microbiome affects our mental state and health.

Companies like [uBiome.com](http://ubiome.com) are attempting to answer that question now.